# To reiterate VS. Reiterating. Do both make sense or does one in this context?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> Ultimately, **to reiterate** what I said in regards to the wallpaper, there are seven large dots at the top, five small dots in the middle, and seven large dots at the bottom.

OR

> Ultimately, **reiterating** what I said in regards to the wallpaper, there are seven large dots at the top, five small dots in the middle, and seven large dots at the bottom.

Do both make sense and mean the same thing, or is one of them the correct one?

Comment: Most native speakers would say [*To **repeat** what I said*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+repeat+what+I+said%2Cto+reiterate+what+I+said&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20repeat%20what%20I%20said%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20reiterate%20what%20I%20said%3B%2Cc0) anyway. But regardless of which verb is used, the infinitive is ***far*** more natural / idiomatic than the continuous participle in such contexts. So using the less-favoured version might be thought to imply *something* (why else would you do it?), but it's not particularly fixed

Comment: As a native speaker, I'd have to say that if another native speaker chose to use the less common verb AND/OR the less common tense, the intended "nuance" would probably be context-specific anyway (I wouldn't expect a competent native speaker to make EITHER of those choices for no reason at all). But I can at least imagine that ***reiterating*** rather than ***to repeat*** might more strongly imply that the relevant point is being (re-)made in some subtly different way that the audience might not realise unless it was explicitly pointed out (by a form of words that naturally draws attention! :)

Comment: As a native speaker, I'd find 'As I said/say' or 'To recap'  more natural-sounding. 'As I said' sounds more towards the upbraiding ('Listen, will you!?) pragmatic extreme.